# VPhantom does not work in overleaf

Tags: split

I tried to use `vphantom{...}` and overleaf does not take `breaqn` package, so I still have the question:

I have the following formula, but I get an error with it that I can't fix. What is wrong here really?

```
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
     \psi(x)=\sum_{j=1}^l\sum_{v=0}^{m_j-1}U_v(x,\mu)V_{m_j-1-v}(\psi,\mu)\left|_{\mu=\mu_j}\\
     +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{\pi\alpha(\sqrt{\mu})\alpha(-\sqrt{\mu})}\left\{e^+(x,\sqrt{\mu})e^+(\psi,-\sqrt{\mu})\\+e^-(x,\sqrt{\mu})e^-(\psi,\sqrt{-\mu})\right\}d\mu
  \end{split}
 \end{equation}
```

The preamble is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand\Setst[3][big]{\csname #1l\endcsname\{ #2 : 
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#3\csname #1r\endcsname \}\end{array}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \doublespacing
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=1, title=Alphabetical Index]


\newcommand{\footremember}[2]{%
    \footnote{#2}
    \newcounter{#1}
    \setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}%
}
\newcommand{\footrecall}[1]{%
    \footnotemark[\value{#1}]%
```

and the comment by overleaf is:

```
 Extra }, or forgotten \right.
    Missing \right. inserted.
    Missing } inserted.
    Extra \right.
    Missing { inserted.
    Thanks
```

equations

Comment: you still have `\left|_{\mu=\mu_j}\\ ` despite this being the third question you have posted  on this. How else can we say it. that does not work, change `\left` to `\bigl` and change `\right` to `\bigr`.

Comment: posting the preamble separately, including lots of packages not needed to show the problem makes it harder for anyone to trace. Please always post complete small documents that show the problem.  but this is a duplicate of the previous ones

Comment: note also that your example code is completely unrelated to your question. Your question title asks about \Vphantom (presumably you meant \vphantom) but your example code does not use that at all.

Comment: " overleaf does not take breaqn" That was explained in comments to your previous question _as well_. The package is breqn not breaqn.

Answer (score 1):

Please always post complete documents. As noted in comments on your earlier questions, you cannot use `\left` and `\right` across cells of the alignment; use `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` instead.

Also, since you're using a `split` environment, do insert `&` alignment points (one per line). If you don't provide alignment points, all rows will be typeset flushright -- probably not what you intend.

This really is a duplicate but I'm answering as you haven't followed previous duplicate references.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "split" environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
     \psi(x) &=\sum_{j=1}^l \sum_{v=0}^{m_j-1} U_v(x,\mu) 
       V_{m_j-1-v}(\psi,\mu) \biggr|_{\mu=\mu_j}\\
     &\quad +\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
       \frac{\sqrt{\mu}}{\pi\alpha(\sqrt{\mu})\alpha(-\sqrt{\mu})}
       \Bigl\{  e^+(x,\sqrt{\mu})e^+(\psi,-\sqrt{\mu})\\
     &\qquad +e^-(x,\sqrt{\mu})e^-(\psi, \sqrt{-\mu}) 
       \Bigr\} d\mu
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of adding explicit `&` alignment points -- 1 per row. Feel free to revert. :-)

Comment: @Mico thanks: must admit I hardly looked at the output, just concentrated on the errors:-)

Comment: Thanks Mico and David. This worked well. I can't believe I forgot to  have amsmath in the preamble...Sorry

Comment: @user287546 ???? you did have amsmath in the preamble in your question.

Comment: Indeed! I thought I didn't for a moment, as he did add it in his preamble.

Comment: @user287546 this answer just does exactly what was said on your  previous questions, changed  `\left` to `\bigl` (or `Bigl` etc) and `\right` to `\bigr` actually you don't need `amsmath` in your version as you have `mathtools` (which includes `amsmath`)